# Ridgline plot of several groups in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have the following data:

```
data<-data.frame(age= rnorm(100, 50, 2), symptom_1 = rbinom(100, 1, 0.5), symptom_2 = rbinom(100, 1, 0.5), symptom_3 = rbinom(100, 1, 0.5), symptom_4 = symptom_1 = rbinom(100, 1, 0.5), death= rbinom(100, 1, 0.75))
```

I would like to represent a ridgline chart with x = age, in y density of death and that every symptom would be a line in the ridgline chart.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi and thanks for your question.  I'll walk you through an example of a workflow that answers your question.  First of all, I'll use `data`, but first, I'm starting with setting the seed for randomization (so that you can see identical results to me).  Also, I'm using functions here from the tidyverse, and we'll create the ridgeline chart using the package `ggridges`, so here's the full library/environment prep:

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
library(ggridges)
set.seed(1234)
data<-data.frame(age= rnorm(100, 50, 2), symptom_1 = rbinom(100, 1, 0.5), symptom_2 = rbinom(100, 1, 0.5), symptom_3 = rbinom(100, 1, 0.5), symptom_4 = rbinom(100, 1, 0.5), death= rbinom(100, 1, 0.75))
```

#### Step 1: Melt or Gather the data

There are a few ways to approach this, but the format of your original dataframe has the same information separated across many columns. It's generally best practice to follow [Tidy Data Principles](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tidyr/vignettes/tidy-data.html).  Our aim with the code below is to combine the information in `data$symptom_1` through `data$symptom_4`, to be the label column, and then just keep `data$age`, `data$Symptom` (our new column), and `data$death`:

```
df <- data %>% gather(key='Symptom', value='Value',-death,-age)
df <- df %>% dplyr::filter(Value==1) %>% select(age, Symptom, death)
```

#### Step 2: Plot the Data

Now that we have the data in the format needed, we'll plot the data.  This is pretty simple.  First, let's create the basic overlapping density plot via `geom_density` and a bit of theme element adjustments to make it look a bit better:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=age)) + theme_minimal() +
  geom_density(aes(fill=Symptom), alpha=0.3) +
  xlim(min(df$age)-2,max(df$age)+2)
```

[image]

Looks okay, but the `ggridges` packages has `geom_density_ridges` that can make our ridgeline density plot for us.  The only other element necessary is to supply a `y=` aesthetic:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=age, y=Symptom)) + theme_minimal() +
  geom_density_ridges(aes(fill=Symptom), alpha=0.3) +
  xlim(min(df$age)-2,max(df$age)+2)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for your explanation!!! It's one of the best answers I have received!

Comment: Glad to help :)